# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8.2 Gb

Tags: r, memory-management

I am trying to run the following code. However, I keep receiving this error "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8.2 Gb"

```
DF4n<-rbindlist(list(df5,df10,df15,df20,df25,df30,df35,df40,df45,df50,df55,df60))
```

System configuration
System type-64-bit operating system
RAM SIZE- 16 GB

What I have tried?

a) Increased memory limit: `memory.limit(size = 10000000000000)`

b) Tried this too.

```
install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE)
devtools::install_github("krlmlr/ulimit")
ulimit::memory_limit(2000)
```

Error received:

Error: Failed to install 'ulimit' from GitHub:
(converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp2Lh2ss/file3238463018a2/ulimit_0.0-3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Your machine does not have enough RAM. The error is just telling you that allocating an additional 8.2GB puts you over the limit

Comment: I'm inferring that each of your `df5`, `df10`, ... frames are not small. Though it'd be nice if `rbindlist` were able to do concatenation of multiple frames in-place, I think that's unlikely, suggesting that each frame will exist in memory *twice* during concatenation. You might have better luck either (a) doing this piecemeal, such as 5 frames at a time; or (b) concatenating outside of R, perhaps a literal `cat df5.csv df10.csv ... > dfall.csv` (taking care to avoid duplicated column headers) or similar.

Comment: Another thought would be to use a DBMS for this, though you're going to run into other performance-based issues (the `DBI` package is great but not very fast with inserts). An "easy" dbms would be to use `RSQLite`, but that has some data-type limitations that can be frustrating. If this is just temporary work, you could always `docker.exe` something like postgresql, mariadb, or sql-server (lots of personal preferences) to do your work (it works rather well).

Comment: (But in a pinch ... if all frames are identically-structured, just write them all to file, `rm(...)` from memory, concatenate outside of R, and read them back in.)